# Angular material autocomplete not working, no errors shown

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-material2

I've implemented my autocomplete, no errors, everything seems ok however absolutely nothing happens. I enter something in the input field and no action seems to happen, nothing is shown in the console.

HTML

```
  <form>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let n of testValues" [value]="n">
        {{n}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </form>
```

TS

```
import { MatAutocomplete } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
...
public testValues = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
public myControl: FormControl;
...
constructor() {
    this.myControl = new FormControl();
}
```

EDIT: I have imported

```
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
```

in my app module.

Version of material -

```
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
```

Comment: Have you put MatAutocompleteModule in your module imports?

Comment: Yes, I have it in my module imports

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are missing a filter method in your `.ts`

You have to subscribe to your `myControl` `valueChanges` this way:

```
this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(newValue=>{
    this.filteredValues = this.filterValues(newValue);
})
```

So everytime your form control value changes you call your custom `filterValues()` method, that should look like:

```
filterValues(search: string) {
    return this.testValues.filter(value=>
    value.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

So you use your `testValues` array as a base array, and your `filteredValues` array in your html:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let n of filteredValues" [value]="n">
    {{n}}
</mat-option>
```

Filtering is not automatic, you have to use your custom method to filter the options. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it should work with a filter. Thanks for taking the time, I tried using yours but it gives me 'Cannot find name "startWith"' and 'Cannot find name map'. Am I  missing some import here?

Comment: @SimeonNakov you're missing your imports from rxjs.

import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';